# Google Earth Engine: calculate mean monthly cloudless NDVI values per zone

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi

I'm using a ZCTA shapefile from the US census and I would like to calculate the mean monthly NDVI value for each ZCTA over a multi-year period. I would also like to look at cloud-free composites. I would want to export this as a .csv with each ZCTA and the corresponding mean NDVI, ~50 months.

I've tried out different methods/code, but I'm having a really hard time consolidating what different people have done to fit what I want to look at.

```
var region = table
var modisNDVI = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_32DAY_NDVI')

Map.addLayer(region)

var aoi = Map.getBounds(true)
var startDate = ee.Date('2015-12-01')
var endDate = ee.Date('2020-01-31')

var modisNDVI = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_32DAY_NDVI')
  .filterBounds(aoi)
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .map(function (image) {
    return image
  })

var numberOfMonths = endDate.difference(startDate, 'months')
var monthOffsets = ee.List.sequence(0, numberOfMonths.subtract(1))
var monthlyNdviCollection = ee.ImageCollection(
  monthOffsets.map(function (monthOffset) {
    var dateRange = startDate
      .advance(ee.Number(monthOffset), 'months')
      .getRange('month')
    return modisNDVI
      .filterDate(dateRange)
      .median()
      .set('system:time_start', dateRange.start().millis())
      .set('system:time_end', dateRange.end().millis())
  })
)

Map.addLayer(monthlyNdviCollection)

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: monthlyNdviCollection,
  description: 'ndvi',
  selectors: [aoi, 'months', modisNDVI]
})
```